# python delete those keys from dictionary who has same value

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hey I have dictionary like following one

```
dicts = {
'met_293':['81.0175','4','7','7','29.76','23','1','0','22','28.57','2','[KG]EHY' ],
'met_394':['79.9579','4','7','7','29.76','18','3','0','15','28.57','2','EHY[ILV]'],
'met_309':['81.0175','4','7','7','29.76','23','1','0','22','28.57','2','[KG]EHY' ],
'met_387':['79.9579','4','7','7','29.76','18','3','0','15','28.57','2','EHY[ILV]']
}
```

I want to remove keys which have same value like 'met_293' and 'met_309' those two keys have same value at 12th position which is '[KG]EHY' so i want my dictionary like this

```
{
'met_293':['81.0175','4','7','7','29.76','23','1','0','22','28.57','2','[KG]EHY'],
'met_394':['79.9579','4','7','7','29.76','18','3','0','15','28.57','2','EHY[ILV]']
}
```

any help!!!
thanks

Comment: You will be more likely to get an answer if you tell us what you've already tried.

Comment: You mean remove *one* of the keys right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `set` and a dict comprehension:

```
>>> dicts = {'met_293': ['81.0175','4','7','7','29.76','23','1','0','22','28.57','2','[KG]EHY'],'met_394': ['79.9579','4','7','7','29.76','18','3','0','15','28.57','2','EHY[ILV]'],'met_309': ['81.0175','4','7','7','29.76','23','1','0','22','28.57','2','[KG]EHY'],'met_387': ['79.9579','4','7','7','29.76','18','3','0','15','28.57','2','EHY[ILV]']}
>>> seen = set()
>>> {k:v for k,v in dicts.iteritems() 
                                 if v[11] not in seen and not seen.add(v[11])}
{'met_394': ['79.9579', '4', '7', '7', '29.76', '18', '3', '0', '15', '28.57', '2', 'EHY[ILV]'],
 'met_293': ['81.0175', '4', '7', '7', '29.76', '23', '1', '0', '22', '28.57', '2', '[KG]EHY']}
```

The above code is equivalent to:

```
>>> dic = {}
>>> seen = set()
>>> for k,v in dicts.iteritems():
...     if v[11] not in seen:
...         dic[k] = v
...         seen.add(v[11])
...         
>>> dic
{'met_394': ['79.9579', '4', '7', '7', '29.76', '18', '3', '0', '15', '28.57', '2', 'EHY[ILV]'],
 'met_293': ['81.0175', '4', '7', '7', '29.76', '23', '1', '0', '22', '28.57', '2', '[KG]EHY']}
```